# Error while compiling main branch

Tags: maven, compiler-errors, package, netty

I tried to build the git checkout with the command `mvn clean package`. And I am getting the following error:

```
19:53:55.473 [main] WARN  o.o.p.u.m.i.AetherBasedResolver - Error resolving artifactio.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.12.Final-SNAPSHOT:Could not find artifact io.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.12.Final-SNAPSHOT
shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact io.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.12.Final-SNAPSHOT
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
...
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.045 sec <<< FAILURE! - in io.netty.osgitests.OsgiBundleTest
testResolvedBundles(io.netty.osgitests.OsgiBundleTest)  Time elapsed: 1.79 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact io.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.12.Final-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact io.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.12.Final-SNAPSHOT
```

Please help resolve this error. Thanks !!!

Comment: The version given `artifactio.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.12.Final-SNAPSHOT` looks wrong. `4.1.12.Final` can't be snapshot...Try to change the version to `4.1.12.Final`only...

Comment: Now i am getting this error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project netty-testsuite-osgi: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.netty:netty-testsuite-osgi:jar:4.1.12.Final-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact io.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.12.Final in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Shall i try version 4.1.11.Final ? I see that last available on [https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/] is `4.1.11.Final`.

Comment: Yup `4.1.11.Final` is working.

Comment: Thanks for getting me unblocked!!